Maple's RootDecompostion and its relation to literature .
I have trouble understanding what Maple produces on RootSpaceDecomposition and its relation to literature.
If we consider this implementation of root space decomposition of $sl(3)$, Maple gives the following:

But when returning to literature, for example, Knapp, I found the following:

The problem for me is that I do not see the relation between the two decomposition.
For instance, if I consider what Maple gives, I will consider the $\alpha_1=-2e_1-e_2$, but in the literature the number "2"  can not occur because the roots are of the form $e_1-e_2$ etc.
Can someone help?

You are assuming, I think, that because they are both using lowercase $e$ that they are using it to mean the same thing  but they are not.
From what I can see the $e_i$ in the Maple description are a basis for the Lie algebra. The relations imposed on them are just some structure equations of the Lie algebra. I assumed they would line up with the $Eij$ named at the end but the order there is wrong or the naming scheme is weird. It seems clear that $E11$ refers to  the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & -1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\\\end{pmatrix}$ and I would expect $E12$ to refer to the matrix with a $1$ in the $(1,2)$ spot and $0$ elsewhere. But if these are $e_1$ and $e_3$ by the order they appear in the list then we should have $[e_1,e_3] = 2e_3$. Indeed it seems we have $E13 = e_3$ instead.
In the excerpt you quote from Knapp however the $e_i$ are not even elements of the Lie algebra. They are linear functionals on the Cartan subalgebra. So are the roots so it makes sense to write roots as combinations of these. You can use the Killing form to identify them with elements of $\mathfrak{h}$ but I don't think you'll get nice integer combinations relative to the basis given by Maple. Indeed $E11,E22$ seem to refer to the coroots (which is not quite the same thing Knapp is using $E_{11},E_{22}$ to refer to) so will differ from these elements by a factor of $\frac{2}{(\alpha,\alpha)}$.
Edit:
The standard Cartan-Weyl basis that I would expect to use and certainly is what Knapp is using (we will additionally denote $H_i = E_{ii} - E_{(i+1)(i+1)}$) has structure constants given as follows:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
  & H_1 & H_2 & E_{12} & E_{13} & E_{23}& E_{21}& E_{31}& E_{32} \\ 
\hline
   H_1 & 0 & 0 & 2E_{12} & E_{13} & -E_{23}& -2E_{21}& -E_{31}& E_{32} \\
\hline
   H_2 & 0 & 0 & -E_{12} & E_{13} & 2E_{23} & E_{21} & -E_{31}& -2E_{32} \\
\hline
   E_{12} & -2E_{12} & E_{12} & 0 & 0 & E_{13} & H_1 & -E_{23} & 0 \\ 
\hline
   E_{13} & -E_{13} & -E_{13} & 0 & 0 & 0 & -E_{32} & H_1 + H_2 & E_{12} \\
\hline
   E_{23} & E_{23} & -2E_{23} & -E_{13} & 0 & 0 & 0 & E_{21} & H_2 \\
\hline
   E_{21} & 2E_{21} & -E_{21} & -H_1 & E_{32} & 0 & 0 & 0 & -E_{13} \\ 
\hline
   E_{31} & E_{31} & E_{31} & E_{23} & -H_1 -H_2 & -E_{21} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\hline
    E_{32} & -E_{32} & 2E_{32} & 0 & -E_{12} & -H_2 & E_{13} & 0 & 0 \\ 
\hline
\end{array}
$$
From the first two rows we can see the eigenvalues of $H_1,H_2$. Comparing with the Maple version (it was not clear to me before those were supposed to be eigenvalues) it would suggest they are using $E11$ to mean $H_1+H_2 = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & -1\\\end{pmatrix}$ swapping out the top line for
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
H_1 + H_2 & 0 & 0 & E_{12} & 2E_{13} & E_{23}& -E_{21}& -2E_{31}& -E_{32}\\ \hline
\end{array} $$
Which does indeed give the eigenvalues you are looking for and explains my confusion above. For the record, that is a weird choice of basis on the Cartan subalgebra and I'm not sure why Maple has made that choice.

thank you for your response.
but what I am not understanding is that in Maple they are writing $[-2,-1]=E31$ for instance, so this $[-2,1]$ refers to the eignevalue of adh, where h is in the cartan subalgebra.
but in Knapp they do not consider like this.
How can I pass from one to another?

Looking it up on https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=DifferentialGeometry%2FLieAlgebras%2FSimpleLieAlgebraData, $E_{11}$ actually refers to $\pmatrix{1&0&0\0&0&0\0&0&-1}$ but $E_{22}$ to $\pmatrix{0&0&0\0&1&0\0&0&-1}$. That's a bad choice of basis AND naming of that bad basis, but should explain what's going on.

@TorstenSchoeneberg thanks for finding that. That choice is so alien to me it didn't even occur to me that might be what was happening.

@MaryMaths I have added some more detail on where those eigenvalues are coming from. To be clear though Knapp in the excerpt you have quoted has not defined a basis on $\mathfrak{h}$ as yet. I have put in the most likely choice but there is no "passing from one to the other" as yet.

Thanks, I see your edits.
but still think that there are passage from one to other.

@MaryMaths In what sense? There is passage from my basis to Maple's but there is no basis given by Knapp so far in that excerpt (the basis given by only $E_{ij}$'s doesn't work as that is really a basis for $\mathfrak{gl}(3)$, hence my definition of $H_i$)
